# How to make not draggable child elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have parent HTML element I make it draggable.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" style = "width: 10px; height: 10px;">
<div id = "title"></div>
<div class="upperLine">
<img id = "img_close" src = "fileclose.png" onclick="ClosePopUpWin()"></div>
<div id = "content"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#parent').draggable();
```

What is the best way to make child elements not draggable?

Comment: If you drag the parent, it is dragged with everything in it. If you give a child `position: absolute` it will stay fixed inside the viewport but that's your lot I'd say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make an element draggable, but not its child elements, using jQuery UI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681381/how-can-i-make-an-element-draggable-but-not-its-child-elements-using-jquery-ui)

Comment: @Matijs you meant `position:fixed`, right..?