# How can I make the parent div draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div containing three buttons. The div needs to be draggable, so that you can drag all three buttons around the screen together. That works fine, but the problem is that when I click on of the individual buttons it inherits the draggable id and it is draggable on it's own. I do not want that to happen. So my question is: how do I make my buttons draggable, but make them always stay together and keep them clickable. I added the code below, but here is a **JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2ga50vvt/

So to be clear: the div also needs to be draggable through dragging one of the individual buttons, but then the rest of the div needs to stick with it. Now dragging an individual button only moves the button.

P.S. I do not want to use **JQuery UI**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <button ng-click="menu.shown = !menu.shown">MENU</button>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="disconnect()">CLOSE</button>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="">KEYS</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dragging = null;
  $('body').on("mousedown", "#draggable", function(e) {
    $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on').addClass('dragged');
    var el_w = $('.dragged').outerWidth(),
      el_h = $('.dragged').outerHeight();
    $('body').on("mousemove", function(e) {
      if ($dragging) {
        $dragging.offset({
          top: e.pageY - el_h / 2,
          left: e.pageX - el_w / 2
        });
      }
    });
    $dragging = $(e.target);
  }).on("mouseup", ".dragged", function(e) {
    $dragging = null;
    $(this).removeAttr('unselectable').removeClass('dragged');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.dragged {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#draggable {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: red;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: move;
  float: left;
}
```

**Update 1**

This is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2ga50vvt/3/
However when I click on the div and start dragging the center of the div jumps to my cursor. It works great, but it looks a bit wonky. Is there a way to prevent the div from moving to my cursor?

Your help is most welcome.

Comment: Why on Earth is this tagged with `Java`?

Comment: We don't make mistakes, we just make happy accidents.

Comment: The solution is probably the same as for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681381/how-can-i-make-an-element-draggable-but-not-its-child-elements-using-jquery-ui

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet you share a topic about a plugin, but this question is not a plugin, is a customized draggable method.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: My bad! I finally noticed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$dragging = $('#draggable');` instead of `$dragging = $('e.target');`

It will drag div if you try to drag using cursor on button. It will drag `#draggable` instead of target.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ga50vvt/3/)**

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely usable, however not perfect. When I click on the div and start to drag it, the center of the div jumps to my cursor. It works great, but it looks a bit wonky. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the `target` property of the event and `return false` to avoid all not `#draggable` to be draggable.

```
if(e.target.id !== "draggable") {
    return false;
}
```

The edited fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ga50vvt/1/

It works perfectly, but one suggestion: don't target with ids because with this code you can't drag more of one element (ids must be **unique**), so the workaround is to write an attribute or a classname and play with it.

Good luck.

Comment: Maybe I got the OP wrong, but starting to drag with the cursor above the buttons should also be possible, I thought.

Comment: With that, you can't drag the buttons, only the parent (as OP asked)

Comment: Yes I would also like it to be draggable when the user clicks one of the buttons. I edited the question.

Comment: Oh! I understood wrong the question. To achieve that you said, try with the solution of  @ketan http://stackoverflow.com/a/34288491/5035890 , it's good

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're opposed to JQueryUI for it's file size, I'd still recommend a prebuilt solution because why reinvent the wheel?

[Draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/) is a really nifty library that I've used when resource size has been an issue. It's 20k minified (obviously even smaller gzipped) and available on a CDN - which in itself has lots of benefits e.g. caching.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggabilly();
});
```

There's a few CSS hooks, different options, events etc.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/668k2pf1/2/)

Comment: Some people needs to achieve things by himselves. You can try it sometimes too. It's funny :)

Comment: As stated in the question: I do not want to use JQuery UI

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude True. It's good to implement your own stuff to learn but in a production environment you're much better off going with something that's been tested thoroughly. It will save you time in the long and short run. As we don't know OP's situation and to make this question useful to other people in the future, mentioning libraries is still a good idea.

Comment: I agree with that. But in a development production depending on the requirements. Sometimes, the abuse of plugins makes the production webpages horribly slow and buggy. Sometimes is better to make your own plugins that fits exactly with your requirements.